# pwgen: no numbers when outputting into file

Tags: bash

I just tried to output hundreds of passwords to print them out when I noticed that no one actually has numbers in it.

This is what I entered: `$ pwgen -B -N 10000 15 > pw.txt`

But when I execute this `$ pwgen -B -N 10000 15` there **are** numbers outputted in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote `man pwgen`:

```
In addition, for backwards compatibility reasons, when stdout is
not a tty and secure password generation mode has not been requested,
pwgen will generate less secure passwords, as if the -0A options had
been passed to it on the command line. This can be overriden using
the -nc options.
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it's hard to think of the easiest solutions, like searching in the manpages for such a behaviour, sorry for that!